# Instantiate Constant variable in solidity

Tags: solidity

What is the right way to instantiate a constant variable in Solidity?
The following code give me errors when I compile:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract LearnSol {

    function LearnSol() {

    }

    function basicSyntax() returns(uint) {

        uint constant a = 8;  
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Compiling ./contracts/LearnSol.sol...

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:48
        throw e;
        ^
abort(5) at Error
    at jsStackTrace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1:19718)
    at stackTrace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1:19901)
    at abort (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:19:15285)
    at Array.dXb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:11:585101)
    at Array.tX (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:8:557453)
    at Array.eea (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:6:495332)
    at Object.wOb [as dynCall_ii] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:11:540050)
    at invoke_ii (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:1:1275129)
    at Array.ixa (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:7:494308)
    at Object.bVb [as dynCall_viii] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/solc/soljson.js:11:577232)
If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
```

I'm following this reference: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/solidity/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your `const` variables outside of your functions:

```
uint constant a = 8;  

function basicSyntax() returns(uint) {
    return 1;
}
```